# concatenate long and bytearray to another bytearray

Tags: java, arrays, byte, long-integer

I am trying to concatenate long and bytearray to another bytearray.

I tried like this :

```
byte[] value1= new byte[16];
byte[] value2= new byte[16];
byte[] finalvalue = new byte[value1.length + value2.length];
long ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
int val = 100;

ByteBuffer.wrap(value1).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asLongBuffer().put(ts);
ByteBuffer.wrap(value2).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asIntBuffer().put(val);

System.arraycopy(value1, 0, finalvalue, 0, value1.length);
System.arraycopy(value2, 0, finalvalue, value1.length,value2.length);
```

When I tried to print this, I am not getting the correct values. It printing like this

```
BYTEVALUE -95-15-4410659100000000002000000000000000
```

it should print like this

```
- BYTEVALUE- 1354707038625,100
```

Can anyone help me out where I am going wrong.

Help will be appreciated.

**Update:**

**Use to print** values using **StringBuffer** like this:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(finalvalue.length);
for (int i = 0; i < finalvalue.length; i++) {
  sb.append(finalvalue[i]);
}
```

Comment: Show the code that you use to print the output.

Comment: I'm not sure,just taking a guess, is it because it is exceeding the 'byte' limit or something?

Comment: FYI - use `StringBuilder` in preference to `StringBuffer`.

Comment: @DuncanJones yup.. for printing the object I am using that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not doing what you think it is. Consider the following self-contained application:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;

public class ByteArrayTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] value1 = new byte[16];
    byte[] value2 = new byte[16];
    byte[] finalvalue = new byte[value1.length + value2.length];
    long ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int val = 100;

    ByteBuffer.wrap(value1).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asLongBuffer()
        .put(ts);
    ByteBuffer.wrap(value2).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asIntBuffer()
        .put(val);

    System.arraycopy(value1, 0, finalvalue, 0, value1.length);
    System.arraycopy(value2, 0, finalvalue, value1.length, value2.length);

    printByteArray(finalvalue);
  }

  private static void printByteArray(final byte[] array) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(array.length);
    for (byte b : array) {
      sb.append(String.format("%02X", b));
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
  }
}
```

The output of this is:

```
BE26086B3B010000000000000000000064000000000000000000000000000000
```

Splitting this into component parts, we can see why:

- The first sixteen bytes are `BE26086B3B0100000000000000000000`. This is your timestamp in little endian order. If you ignore the zero bytes, this converts to `1,354,710,394,558` in decimal, which is correct.
- The second sixteen bytes are `64000000000000000000000000000000`, which is your hard-coded value `100`.

The zeroes represent the space in the byte arrays that you didn't use.